# Ansible The error was: 'unicode object' has no attribute

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

Hey Guys maybe you can help me on this Problem.
Im trying to create some Folders in my apache role.(The role was initially from geerlenguy)

This is my a part of my vars file for my host:

```
 apache_vhosts:
  - servername: myhost.com
    documentroot: "/var/www/html/web"
    extra_parameters: |
      <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
          RewriteEngine On
          RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
          RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/server-status.*
          RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
      </IfModule>
      <Directory "/var/www/html/web">
        AuthType Basic
        Require valid-user
        AuthName "Please authenticate"
        AuthUserFile /var/www/html/.htpasswd
      </Directory>
  - servername: secondhost.com
    documentroot: "/var/www/learning/web"
    extra_parameters: |
      <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
          RewriteEngine On
          RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
          RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/server-status.*
          RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
        </IfModule>
      <Directory "/var/www/learning/web">
        AuthType Basic
        Require valid-user
        AuthName "Please authenticate"
        AuthUserFile /var/www/learning/.htpasswd
      </Directory>
```

My Task looks like this at the moment:

```
- name: Create Apache vhost Folders
  file:
    path: "{{ item.0.documentroot }}"
    state: directory
    mode: '0755'
    owner: root
    group: root
  with_items:
    - apache_vhosts
```

But this seems to looks like garbage to me. I can't get it to work because of this error:

```
fatal: [webserver.company.com]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'unicode object' has no attribute 'documentroot'
```

Could you guys tell me how to access the `documentroot` var correctly in my Task?
Would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
- name: Create Apache vhost Folders
  file:
    path: "{{ item.documentroot }}"
    ...
  with_items: "{{ apache_vhosts }}"
```

[Migrate from with_X to loop](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#migrating-from-with-x-to-loop)

```
  loop: "{{ apache_vhosts }}"
```

---

Example. The task

```
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.documentroot }}"
      loop: "{{ apache_vhosts }}"
```

gives

```
    "msg": "/var/www/html/web"
    "msg": "/var/www/learning/web"
```

Comment: Hi Botka thanks for the help, but it didn't worked for me. Got the following error: `The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'list object' has no attribute 'documentroot'`

Comment: Works for me as expected. I've added an example.

Comment: Hi Botka thanks again! with the example I made it working... looks like my error came from a different tasks....